# How to make a NAND Gate?

Tags: digital-logic, schematics, logic-gates, nand

Im using 123d circuits by Autodesk and I am trying to make a NAND logic gate.[image]

When i simulate my circuit (one in picture) it does not work and the LED does not turn on. I am using 2 NPN transistors, 2 switches and 3 1k resistors. The battery is 9v. Can someone help me find whats wrong with it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your circuit is a strange mix of upside-down-ness. Figure 1 shows a more-likely-to-work configuration.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fN526m.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. The standard solution to this problem.*

A few tips:

- Draw your schematics with positive rail on top and negative at the bottom. It will be easier to trace current flow from top to bottom.
- Draw inputs on the left and outputs on the right. (You did this.)
- Add a ground symbol somewhere. Even if not connected to the Earth it provides a reference for all measurements taken on the circuit.

Comment: It's not clear from your comment whether you think I stole your answer or you are genuinely grateful. If the former then I can assure you that the idea wasn't stolen as the same AND gate design question has come up several times in the past few weeks. I think visually and find the schematics say far more than text can, are less ambiguous and intelligible to those with weak English. I try to add an illustration to all my answers if I think one will help. We complain when there are no schematics in the questions so I feel it's only right that we add them to our answers.

Comment: Agree. I didn't spend the time to draw a schematic, and they do make things more clear. And I haven't read the other questions, so wouldn't know about other answers.

Answer (score 1):

The battery and diode polarity are opposite to what is required using NPN transistors. With an NPN transistor, the base and collector need to be +ve wrt the emitter for collector to emitter current to flow.

If you substitute PNP transistors, I think the circuit might work.

Comment: I do not think it can work just swapping parts, topology is not right.

Comment: I had to "bend" the circuit a bit to think about it too. If you redraw the circuit with the +ve battery terminal at ground, you will see the diode is in the emitter to ground leg of the transistor totem. I think the topology is OK, just the polarities are wrong.

Comment: for some reason I assumed the pnp emitters would have gone in place of the npn collectors, which won't work. thanks for the clarification

Comment: I'm confused, Does electricity flow from negative to positive or vice versa?

Comment: That's a more complicated question that generally appreciated….Electrons (which constitute electricity in most cases, and certainly in conductive metal wires) flow from negative to positive. In semiconductors we also talk about "holes", which is really a place where an electron could be, but isn't. Holes have a positive charge, and flow from positive to negative, but only in a semiconductor. In an ionic solution, both positive and negative ions can exist, and flow in opposite directions.

Comment: And just to create more confusion, the direction of  "conventional" current flow in analyzing electronic circuits, is assumed to be from positive to negative, i.e. opposite to the direction of electron flow. So when you're analyzing circuits, try not to think about what's actually physically flowing, but that this artificial construct called "conventional" electricity flows from positive to negative.

Comment: Okay thanks for filling me in and one more question is that everytime i design an electronic circuit I should design it going from posotive to negative (unless im using a PNP, sort of)?

Comment: Yes. When using PNP, just think of the current flowing from emitter to collector, which is opposite to the direction it flows in a NPN.